# When i pass array , its says "Input data in wrong format for chart type". [Line Graph]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to send array data to draw chart. I am trying to give input values [x and y] from user by using html. I could be able to get data from html but when i pass to chart the format is not getting recognized. I am using code from [this website](http://www.jscharts.com/how-to-use). In that you can see , values are passed statically. I want to pass dynamically. please help me.

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>JSChart</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jschatrs.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="xText" name="xvalue">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="yText" name="yvalue">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <div id="graph">Loading graph...</div>
    <button onclick="db()">Try it</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function db() {
            var p = document.getElementById("xText").value;
            var q = document.getElementById("yText").value;
            var myData = new Array([0, 0]);
            myData.push([p, q]);
            alert(myData);
            var myChart = new JSChart('graph', 'line');
            myChart.setDataArray(myData);
            myChart.setLineColor('#8D9386');
            myChart.setLineWidth(4);
            myChart.setTitleColor('#7D7D7D');
            myChart.setAxisColor('#9F0505');
            myChart.setGridColor('#a4a4a4');
            myChart.setAxisValuesColor('#333639');
            myChart.setAxisNameColor('#333639');
            myChart.setTextPaddingLeft(0);
            myChart.draw();
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am building a application which reads the data from any external device and directly stores in mobile in text format. It is something like [ origin software] which allows to connect external source to computer and stores in computer in some file format. Can i achieve this by directly plugging external device to mobile? If so i need to know i should write seperate code to read values and store in a file. please guide me how i can achieve this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It may be because the `value` property of input elements is stored as a string. Try parsing them as integers:

```
var p = parseInt(document.getElementById("xText").value, 10);
var q = parseInt(document.getElementById("yText").value, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the values you're retrieving from `xText` and `yText` are strings rather than numbers.

Try this if they're whole integers:

```
var p = parseInt(document.getElementById("xText").value, 10);
var q = parseInt(document.getElementById("yText").value, 10);
```

And this if they're not:

```
var p = parseFloat(document.getElementById("xText").value);
var q = parseFloat(document.getElementById("yText").value);
```